# java.util.Iterator but cannot import java.util.Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

Given this Code

```
import java.util.Iterator;

private static List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    someList.add("monkey");
    someList.add("donkey");

    //Code works when I change Iterator to java.util.Iterator, but import      
    //is not possible?
    for(Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String item = i.next();
        System.out.println(item);
    }

}
```

I receive the error: The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Eclipse tells me that the import java.util.Iterator conflicts with a type defined in the same file.

Comment: Why are you laughing? Do you have your own `Iterator` type?

Comment: @Mifmif:  It's a **perfectly** valid question, since `Iterator<T>` is defined to accept a generic parameter.

Comment: not at all a stupid question @Mifmif, especially since if he DOES have one, that would cause this error.

Comment: @Mifmif: You are correct. It's obvious that the OP has one based on what his/her eclipse is saying. - *... the import java.util.Iterator conflicts with a type defined in the same file.* That's supposed to be the hint right there.

Comment: Well... the import statement is right at the top of this file. Doesn't this show that OP is definitely using the standard Iterator (or was that added recently)?

Comment: @IcedDante no.  Classes local to the project (that is, hand-written) with the same name will override imports.  Therefore, it is necessary to specify which iterator is desired

Comment: Then try `for(java.util.Iterator<String> i ...` and give us the feedback.

Comment: Note: you can do the same like this for(String s: someList) {}

Comment: Couldn't this also be caused by a confused install, such Eclipse is set at language level 1.5+, but the JDK jar it knows about is 1.4?

Comment: @yshavit That wouldn't explain the `The import java.util.Iterator conflicts with a type defined in the same file` message.

Comment: Ah, true, I didn't notice that second error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I receive the error: The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments
>
> Eclipse tells me that the import java.util.Iterator conflicts with a type defined in the same file.

The only way I can get those two exact errors is to call my class `Iterator`. I suppose this would be an easy mistake to make if you were writing a little test class about iteration:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Iterator {

    private static List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someList.add("monkey");
        someList.add("donkey");

        for (Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String item = i.next();
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution: don't do that. Call it something else.

*As fun as it is to try and guess what your code looked like, had you posted an entire example in your question this would have been a shorted process. I'm not ruling out that there's another code sample that produces those errors, although I failed to find one with a bit of experimentation.*

Comment: You wouldn't be able to import `java.util.Iterator`. This question is garbage.

Comment: change the Name of class and then try :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Agreed. Copy/paste my code above into an IDE and you get exactly those two errors. Not sure how this would accidentally happen when using Eclipse code completion and auto-importing...

Comment: this  code doesn't compile at all ! solution : change the name of your class first and try again  !

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And yet somehow it has attracted two up-votes... :-(

Answer (score 0):

check your import statement proper
it may be possible that you have already import iterator that comes from another packages first organize your imports
delete those imports and 
add

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

hope it will works for you

Comment: How would that explain the `The import java.util.Iterator conflicts with a type defined in the same file` message?

Comment: it would not explain by any IDE but one have to check it manually by checking there import statements.